# Clickable SVG paths to open fancybox

Tags: svg, fancybox, anchor, imagemap, clickable

In short, I have a pie chart graphic that when a segment is clicked it should open a fancybox overlay. I tried using a `map` which worked fine but it wasn't 100% accurate, the edges weren't rounded and I can't apply any hover styles.

So I decided to create an SVG with the pie chart segments (paths) on top of the graphic. This means the SVG paths now match the shapes on the pie chart exactly. Here is the code for the SVG:

```
<figure class="align-center">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 760 580" xml:space="preserve">
        <image xlink:href="../../img/content/diagrams/background-graphic.png" x="0" y="0" height="580px" width="760px" />
        <path class="st0" d="M251.9,456.4C287.4,483.7,331.8,500,380,500c11.8,0,23.3-1,34.6-2.8L380,290L251.9,456.4z" />
        <path class="st0" d="M380,80c-116,0-210,94-210,210c0,67.8,32.1,128,81.9,166.4L380,290V80z" />
        <path class="st0" d="M527.3,439.6C566,401.6,590,348.6,590,290c0-116-94-210-210-210v210L527.3,439.6z" />
        <path class="st0" d="M380,290l129.3,165.5c6.3-4.9,12.3-10.2,18-15.8L380,290z" />
        <path class="st0" d="M414.6,497.2c35.3-5.9,67.7-20.5,94.8-41.7L380,290L414.6,497.2z" />
    </svg>
</figure>
```

Now I need to somehow make the `path` element behave like an anchor. You could add an `href` to the `area` elements within a `map` but it doesn't seem like you can do that with an SVG?

There markup for the hidden content is simple and looks like this:

```
<div id="overlay-1" class="hide">
    <h3>Overlay title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

The usual behaviour would be this opens once an object with the corresponding href value was clicked.

What's the best practice for this - if there is such a thing?

Comment: wrap each path in an <a> tag.

Comment: That works for URL's but the content I'm trying to load is in a hidden div using fancybox. Wrapping a path in am anchor with an href referencing the ID of the content I want to display doesn't work and gives a `Uncaught TypeError` error in the console.

Comment: you can run javascript to unhide the fancybox when the anchor is clicked.

Comment: Fancybox does that automatically, normally but apparently not when it's within an SVG. Unfortunately I can't update fancybox.js or the script which triggers a box to be shown as the 1 file is used across 5 different apps. So changing that could break what works in the other apps. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can attach click event to your element, then there is no reason why it could not be used to trigger fancyBox.

Simply add `data-src` and `data-fancybox` attributes if using fancyBox v3.

Example:

`<path data-fancybox data-src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3953/15594397982_477385f90d_b_d.jpg" class="st0" d="M251.9,456.4C287.4,483.7,331.8,500,380,500c11.8,0,23.3-1,34.6-2.8L380,290L251.9,456.4z" />`

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJreVd?editors=1000

Another solution would be to create custom click event for your path elements and call fancyBox manually. Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ymhvdeqy/1/

Comment: Unfortunately the version is 2.1.5. Not sure I can update it as it's a core JS file for multiple apps so it might break everything else, sadly! Such a shame I can't use that because it looks great.

Comment: You can add `href` attributes and apply fancyBox manually, for example, using `$('path').fancybox()` (choose your own selector)

Comment: Would that work like this: `<path href="$('#overlay-1').fancybox()" d="" />` Just I can't get that to work. Tried with `class="fancybox"` added too. Thanks again.

Comment: No, it does not work that way :) For example, something like this - `<path href="#overlay-1" class="st0" ..` and then somewhere put `$('.st0').fancybox();`

Comment: I've tried that, with the `$('.class').fancybox();` at the bottom of the page (after the fancybox js) but on click I get a console error like: `Uncaught TypeError: element.prop(...).match is not a function` - maybe it can't work with paths? Maybe I need to rethink this! :)

Comment: I created a CodePen if it's any clear, to check I'm not doing anything stupid with the JS! https://codepen.io/moy/pen/gxjaqN

Comment: I have updated answer with link to another demo showing how to call fancyBox manually.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this in an hour when I'm back at my computer. Looks great though! I think I know the answer to this from a previous experience - but there a way to combine my fancybox call and yours to minimise the code? I think I tried that with something else but ended up needing to have 2 separate ones and declare all the same options again otherwise it wouldn't work and wouldn't look the same if I didn't.

Comment: Sure, either like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ymhvdeqy/2/ - or simply make custom click event for all fancyboxed links - http://jsfiddle.net/og1z0eh2/

Comment: Thanks man! I guess the good thing about having them separate could be that I can add a 2nd class for instances when FB doesn't work? They look quite similar to the 'normal' script I run but I guess as the link is within a SVG it just needs a little something added to make it work. It was odd as FB was always activated on a class but this needed the `.open` part added?

Comment: This overcomes the issue you were having. Strangely, jQuery `prop('class')`  returns object on svg elements, but fancyBox expects string.

Comment: Nice one, I don't know much JS so all this goes over my head a bit - so thanks for explaining! Which approach would you recommend using out of the JS Fiddle examples? Keeping the separate or the combined version? Thanks again, you've been a massive help!

Comment: I figured that if the 'normal' FancyBox functionality works the same with the `.open` bit maybe I should use that across the board?

Comment: Well, it is up to you how to use it. There is no big difference anyway, because calling $().fancybox() just attaches click handler that calls $.fancybox.open(). And it is perfectly fine to create your own click handler and do that manually.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I trigger FancyBox by adding a class (.fancybox) to an anchor anyways, so maybe this method is the most similar to that? http://jsfiddle.net/og1z0eh2/